# Find Specific Text Values With TinyXML

Tags: c++, tinyxml

i have xml file like below.I want to find specific text values in different times.How can i access the text values with TinyXML

```
    -<language>
      <text value="Advanced Sensor Controls" parameter="title"/>
      <text value="Refresh" parameter="refresh_button"/>
      <text value="Show" parameter="button_show"/>
      <text value="Hide" parameter="button_hide"/>
      <text value="Raw Command" parameter="label_raw_command_title"/>
      <text value="Expected RX" parameter="label_raw_command_expected_rx"/>
    </language>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the `TiXmlDocument`;
2. Get the root `TiXmlElement`;
3. Get the `FirstChild()` named 'text';
4. Get the value of the `Attribute()` named 'value', do something with it;
5. Get the `NextSibling()` element named 'text';
6. Repeat until no more siblings.

Comment: i don't want to do it like a loop,for example i want to access "Raw Command" text without using or accessing the others.

Comment: You're going to have to iterate and inspect, there's no way to differentiate that specific element from all it's siblings.

Answer (score 3):

With help of code such this:

```
TiXmlDocument file( xmlfilename );
TiXmlElement *language = file.FirstChildElement("language");
for(TiXmlElement *text =
        language->FirstChildElement(
                "text");
    text;
    text =
        language->NextSiblingElement() )
{
    text->Attribute("value"); // this returns text in value=""
    text->Attribute("parameter"); // this returns text in parameter=""
}
```

Comment: sorry,but i can not understand the differences between the method of first post.it is in same mind,loop mind.Is not it ???

Comment: Yes, it is the same. I have posted this and then saw the first post was submitted.